# Operator || is undefined for the argument type boolean, String

Tags: string, csv, boolean, parallel-coordinates

I'm trying to create a Parallel Coordinate graph with a csv file I have. The graph I'm trying to make looks like the image I have drawn here -> [DrawnGraph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Vqvp.jpg). The issue I am having is that the countries are listed individually on the csv file. I need to create a code that places the countries within their corresponding continents. I attempted the code below but I keep getting "The operator || is undefined for the argument type(s) boolean, String"
I realize that I am typing it wrong but I do not know how to fix it. Help please

```
    if(Country.equals("Aruba")||Country.equals("Argentina")||Country.equals("Bolivia")||Country.equals("Brazil")||Country.equals("Chile")||("Columbia")||Country.equals("Ecuador")||Country.equals("Guyana")||Country.equals("Paraguay")||Country.equals("Peru")||Country.equals("Suriname")||Country.equals("Uruguay")||Country.equals("Venezuela"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're missing an occurrence of `Country.equals` here:

```
Country.equals("Chile")||("Columbia")||Country.equals("Ecuador")
```

Add that in and it ought to work.

By the way, you haven't specified what programming language you're using. You probably should.

Comment: yes that fixed it, thanks
and sorry, first question, i am using Processing